# I can run %in% code on dummy data but not real data

Tags: r

Thanks in advance.  Using the below dummy data I can create an indicator variable, `a1$r` in data frame, `a1` where two columns in `a1` match two columns in `a2`.  As such:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,6,3,4), b=letters[1:4])
a1$r <- ifelse(a1$a %in% a2$a & a1$b %in% a2$b,  1,0) 
a1
```

However when I try to replicate this on my actual data, the code works but it returns the "wrong" answer.  I would love to define wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly it's doing.    I have tried several approaches including `match` but to no avail.  I have a feeling its something intrinsic about my data - but I can't figure out what. All variables are encoded as numeric.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Is the "wrong" answer off by 1? Completely off the mark with no relationship to the right answer?

Comment: values of `1` are given when they shouldn't be...that's really all I can figure out at this point...

Comment: Are you *sure* they are all numeric. Did you check the `class()` of each column? If you can't make the problem reproducible, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pitfall is probably the following:

```
a1 = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
a2 = data.frame(a = c(2,1,3), b = letters[1:3])

a1$r = ifelse(a1$a %in% a2$a & a1$b %in% a2$b,  1,0) 
a1
#  a b r
#1 1 a 1
#2 2 b 1
#3 3 c 1
```

Everything matched (because each condition is evaluated separately and the two are not evaluated together row by row), but I'm guessing you expected only the last one to match.

What you want instead is a join operation and I'd do it using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to `data.table` in place
setDT(a1)
setDT(a2)

# set the keys for the join
setkey(a1, a, b)

# fill r initially with 0's, then set to 1 only those that will match the join
a1[, r := 0][a2, r := 1]
a1
#   a b r
#1: 1 a 0
#2: 2 b 0
#3: 3 c 1
```

Comment: I don't understand answers like this. you could have fixed the example code with `==` instead of `%in%`. Instead, your answer was `1) abandon base r, 2) install this new package, 3) learn the new snytax, 4) go back to your problem and fix it`

Comment: @rawr you can't fix OP's problem using `==`. I suggest writing down the base answer first and then it might be clear why I prefer the `data.table` solution.

Comment: youre right. I used it on your example. Are you referring to the problems with number of rows? or the factor levels? either of those are easily remedied

Comment: @rawr I'm referring to the fact that base solutions for this problem are going to be long/difficult to read/understand, won't scale, will be fragile, etc - take your pick.

Comment: Many thanks...I though that the issue might be that each condition was not being evaluated simultaneously - but I didn't know how to check for this.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: slyly ignoring the simple solution and also my comment about learning the new syntax of data table for data which you are purporting to have 10 million rows.. ookay

Comment: @rawr once more - there is no comparably simple base solution to the problem at hand - if you think there is - you're encouraged to post that as an answer; and it seems like you only saw one of the 3 reasons I mentioned.

Comment: @eddi doing a JOIN is indeed the right way to go... and it's perfectly feasible to do that in base R as well using `merge` (not that there is anything wrong in doing it with `data.table` mind you).

Comment: @plannapus feasible - sure, but it's not going to be easy or pretty

Answer (score 1):

A simpler (though not necessarily scalable) approach is to use `duplicated` and `rbind`.

Using @eddi's sample data:

```
a1 = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
a2 = data.frame(a = c(2,1,3), b = letters[1:3])

duplicated(rbind(a1, a2), fromLast=TRUE)[sequence(nrow(a1))]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Wrap that in `as.numeric` to get ones and zeroes instead of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s.

This won't work as is if you expect duplicates within "a1" or "a2".

---

The other crude idea that comes to mind is:

```
do.call(paste, a1) %in% do.call(paste, a2)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to @eddi answer but using base R:

```
a1 = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
a2 = data.frame(a = c(2,1,3), b = letters[1:3])

#Do a join using function merge on one of the column:

A = merge(a1,a2,by="b") #Here I chose to join on column b but you can as well join on a.
A
#  b a.x a.y
#1 a   1   2
#2 b   2   1
#3 c   3   3

#Check if the other column match:
a1$r = ifelse(A[,2]==A[,3], 1, 0) #Note here the use of == and not %in% as we're comparing pairwise.
a1
#  a b r
#1 1 a 0
#2 2 b 0
#3 3 c 1
```

**Edit**: In case your a1 contains values that are not in a2 you need to use argument `all` in `merge`:

```
a1 = data.frame(a = c(1:3,3), b = letters[1:4])
a2 = data.frame(a = c(2,1,3), b = letters[1:3])
A = merge(a1,a2,by="b",all=TRUE)
A
#  b a.x a.y
#1 a   1   2
#2 b   2   1
#3 c   3   3
#4 d   3  NA
a1$r = ifelse(A[,2]==A[,3], 1, 0)
a1$r[is.na(a1$r)] = 0
```

**Edit**

```
A = merge(a1,a2,by="b",all=TRUE)
A$r = ifelse(A[,2]==A[,3],1,0)
A$r[is.na(A$r)] = 0
a1 = merge(a1,A[,c("b","r")],by="b")
```

works for all case figures.

Comment: doesn't work for e.g. `a1 = data.frame(a = c(1:3,3), b = letters[1:4])` and same `a2`

Comment: still not quite there - here are your next two failure points in one example: `a1 = data.frame(a = 1, b = 'a'); a2 = data.frame(a = 1, b = c('a','a','b'))`

Comment: run the `data.table` solution to see what you should get (as is it just gives an error)

Comment: I can't run the data.table example: i have R 2.14 on a computer on which I'm not admin and can't install things. data.table needs R 2.15

Comment: And as I said, if you switch `a1` and `a2` there is no error whatsoever with your example.

Comment: how is it relevant that you don't get an error when switching the two? In this case the result should simply be `a1$r = 1` since the combo `a=1` and `b='a'` exists in `a2`; your current solution dies on that example for two reasons - one because of the sizes and two because of the duplicate in `a2`

Comment: The OP example clearly illustrates that `a1` does NOT contain the complete suit of possible values. I'm sorry you see this as nitpicking - I'm simply pointing out that you're not fully there yet (you can be, but you're not yet).

Comment: @eddi I edited with a solution that should take care of all case studies. With your last example it does show the line duplicated (that s a quirk of `merge`, one would need to run a `!duplicated` on top of everything to get rid of that). Well i did see it as nitpicking considering that the whole purpose of my post was just to demonstrate that they were adequate tools in base R as well, without really extending on it initially (the OP question being somewhat incomplete anyway). But that's no biggy.

Comment: @rawr I think this answer is a perfect illustration of why one would not want to use base R for this problem. After all the edits it still doesn't work (not to mention that readability is non-existent). plannapus - I'm removing the -1 for the effort, but cannot in good faith give this a +1 as it still doesn't work.